# dbeaver rename table column name in mysql 8.0.24

Tags: mysql, dbeaver

I am using dbeaver to rename a table's column name. It is mysql 8.0.24. The connection is good and I can do update, insert, select and so on operations. But when I try to do the rename column operation. The operation runs forever and never be done. Is there any magic that I need to do in dbeaver before I do the rename?

```
alter table mydata.user_login rename column user_name to username;
```

Best regards

Comment: If you open another MySQL client window and run SHOW PROCESSLIST, does it say "waiting for table metadata lock" on the line for your alter table? (assuming you haven't interrupted the alter table and it is still 'running')

Comment: @Bill Karwin, yes there is waiting for table metadata lock. What is that?

Comment: I explain it in my answer to the duplicate question I have linked to.

Comment: But there is only one query in my processlist. Why it still has the metadata lock? I can understand that if there are two query at the same time. But for my case, there is only one query.

Comment: They may be no query running, but the transaction that ran that query still holds the metadata lock until it commits.